# how to make zipcode field takes it value from a dropdown list of cities? and updates

Tags: woocommerce, dropdown, zipcode, city

woocommerce.
how to make zipcode field takes it value from a dropdown list of cities after a user select his required city? and updates the checkout so the available shipping options appears
demo.baytalebaa.com
at checkout you can see there is a dropdown list of cities . i need the zipcode to take the exact value of the choosen city even if its 'jeddah' for example , and store it. note that the user can change the city and by that it needs to update again,
http://prntscr.com/k6mc7b

Answer (score 0):

Another poster asked the same here: [Woocommerce: How Zipcode populates automatically based on city field seleced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400667/woocommerce-how-zipcode-populates-automatically-based-on-city-field-seleced)

An existing plugin was the closest solution, yet far from ideal.